# Maven dependency exclusion from transitive dependency of spring-context

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-2

I want to exclude the `common-logging` from `spring-core` but `spring-core` is a transitive dependency for `spring-context`. I did it in the next way, but it seem to me that there is more properly way. What is it???

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: i want to use slf4j along log4j http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging-slf4j

Comment: You can still use `sfl4j` (I am using log4j with spring); nothing is stopping you. However, in order to use spring in a project, you need `spring-core` which requires `commons-logging`. Include it but don't use it yourself.

Comment: @William Callahan: Look at [Bridging legacy APIs](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude transitive dependencies, see [Introduction to the Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies):

> - *Excluded dependencies* - If project X depends on project Y, and project Y depends on project Z, the owner of project X can explicitly exclude project Z as a dependency, using the "exclusion" element.

Example:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The problem is that `commons-logging` is _not an optional_ dependency; how can this be excluded? (If it were provided somewhere else?)

Comment: @William Callahan: You have to replace it or you have to know, that you never use functionality that depends on the removed dependency.